# How to create MySQL trigger to copy newly inserted data in one table to another

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have 3 MySQL tables: table1,table2 table3. I am trying to extract specific content from table1 and table2 then insert this extracted content to table3 via use of a trigger. I want the trigger to insert this new record whenever data is inserted into table1

```
CREATE trigger 'test_trigger' after insert on 'table1'

select a.fname, a.lname,b.address,b.contact 
from table1 a 
inner join table2
on a.table1_id=b.table2_id

insert into table3(fname,lname,address,contact)

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

The INSERT statement can insert the values selected by a SELECT statement:

```
insert into table3(fname, lname, address, contact)
    select a.fname, a.lname, b.address, b.contact 
      from table1 a 
     inner join table2
        on a.table1_id = b.table2_id
```

Note that you probably want a WHERE clause to limit the amount of data inserted each time.  As written, all the joinable data in the two tables is inserted into Table3 each time any row is inserted into Table1.

Comment: would this only apply to newly inserted data?

Comment: No. The SELECT is not constrained to just the new data. You'll need to look up the syntax for CREATE TRIGGER in MySQL but there is usually a way to say something like `REFERENCING NEW AS xyz` and then qualifying the WHERE clause to select just the newly inserted data (`WHERE a.table1_id = xyz.table1_id` or something similar).

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE trigger 'test_trigger' after insert on 'table1'

insert into table3 (fname, lname, address, contact)
    select a.fname, a.lname,b.address,b.contact 
    from table1 a 
    inner join table2 on a.table1_id=b.table2_id
    where a.id = NEW.id

END;
```

untested, but should work... you've got OLD and NEW in triggers, which are useable like table-aliases (your a for example), for inserts you only have NEW, for update NEW and OLD, for delete OLD